# Генерация JSON-Файла из DB

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Появился запрос и идея, реализации изменения разных конфигураций в программе глобально, чтобы их видел каждый пользователь - например цвета какой-то кнопки.

Для этого, пришла в голову идея, использовать `JSON`, который будет читаться из БД, генерироваться и сообственно сообщать пользователю о тех или иных конфигураций. Идея может не самая лучшая, критерии и другие более лучшие варианты принимаются.

Создал в БД новую таблицу `config_example` c двумя `column` - `configName` и `configValue`.
После создал в приложении подключение через `DataSet` и пытаюсь с помощью Newonsoft.JSON сгенирировать файл таким образом

```
    public class JsonDataTable
    {
        public string Schema { get; set; }
        public string Table { get; set; }

        public static JsonDataTable FromDataTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            JsonDataTable j = new JsonDataTable();
            var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => new { DataPropertyName = c.ColumnName, DataPropertyType = c.DataType.ToString() });
            j.Schema = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns);
            j.Table = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\example.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j.Table));

            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"C:\example.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, j.Table);
            }
            return j;
        }
    }
```

пример взять частично из интернета.
Сообственно, файл я получаю, однако он не соответвует стандарту `JSON`.
Выглядит все вот так:

```
"[
    {
        \"configName\":\"ColorUmsatzDiagramPuergenHintergrund\",
        \"configValue\":\"#BFBFBF\"
    },
    {
        \"configName\":\"ColorSome\",
        \"configValue\":\"#000000\"
    }
]"
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` `File.CreateText` - зачем вы 2 раза перезаписываете один и тот же файл? Не пойму, в чем именно проблема, в том что струтура json содержит escape символы `\ ` и лишние кавычки? Какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: @aepot `File.WriteAllText` и `File.CreateText` взят из примера `Newonsoft.JSON`. И да, проблема в том, что JSON cодержит `\ `  и лишние кавычки. `JSON Parser` ругается, что это не `JSON`.

Comment: уберите весь блок с `using (StreamWriter` и попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: как коллега @aepot правильно заметил весь блок using можно убрать достаточно:             File.WriteAllText(@"C:\example.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j.Table));

Comment: `j.Table = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);` - здесь происходит первая сериализация. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j.Table)` - здесь вторая. Отсюда лишние кавычки.

Comment: @aepot, WinnerIT, AlexanderPetrov спасибо, помогло